# Add special characters to regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I have this validation in my model:

`validates :field, length: { maximum: 20 }, format: { with: /\A('|\p{L}|\s|-)*\z/ }`

it is validating that `field` should contain only unicode letters, apostrophes, dashes and spaces.

Also, i would like permit these special characters in this regexp:

```
%w[
    Ä É Ö Ü ß ä é ö ü À Â Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Î Ï Ô Œ Ù Û Ü Ÿ à â æ ç
    è é ê ë î ï ô œ ù û ü ÿ Á É Í Ñ Ó Ú Ü ¿ ? á é í ñ ó ú ü ! ¡
    À È É Ì Ò Ù à è é ì ò ù Ć Ą Ę Ł Ń Ó Ś Ź Ż ć ą ę ł ń ó ś ź ż
    Á Â Ã À Ç É Ê Í Ó Ô Õ Ú á â ã à ç é ê í ó ô õ ú
  ]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are these letters? Aren't they already matched with `\p{L}`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i can not add these special characters with that validation, right now

Comment: Wiktor's point is that `'Ä'.match?(/\p{L}/) #=> true`, so there is no need to add `'Ä'` or any of the other characters. Do you want to match English characters or those specified Unicode letters?

Comment: I have downvoted and voted to close your question because it is unclear. Please edit your question to clarify it. If you do I will retract my downvote and vote to close. You need to do this even though you've selected an answer. In future don't be so hasty to select an answer. You don't want to discourage other answers or short-circuit those still working on answers. There's no rush. I suggest waiting a minimum of two hours.

Comment: Even though the question has been closed it may be reopened if you clarify with an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current regexp matches all those chars EXCEPT for: `¡` `¿` `!` and `?`. Try with `\A[-\p{L}'\s!¡¿\?]*\z` (you don't need to separate everything with `|`)

https://rubular.com/r/lbHMMGxWY6wqMH

Comment: ohhh my bad, thank you very much!

Comment: Good catch that a few of the "special characters" are not letters. I expect most readers were like me, stopping their scan after looking at the first few characters.